# Почему цифры в калькуляторе заменяют друг друга?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Нужно, чтобы числа записывались по порядку, а не заменяли друг друга.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from calc import Ui_MainWindow

class win(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(win, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_1)
        self.ui.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_2)
        self.ui.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_3)
        self.ui.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_4)
        self.ui.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_5)
        self.ui.pushButton_7.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_6)
        self.ui.pushButton_8.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_7)
        self.ui.pushButton_9.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_8)
        self.ui.pushButton_10.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_9)
        self.ui.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_10)
        self.ui.pushButton_12.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_11)
        self.ui.pushButton_13.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_12)
        self.ui.pushButton_14.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_13)
        self.ui.pushButton_15.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked_14)

        self.setWindowTitle('Калькулятор')

    def btnClicked(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('1')
    def btnClicked_1(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('2')
    def btnClicked_2(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('3')
    def btnClicked_3(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('4')
    def btnClicked_4(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('5')
    def btnClicked_5(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('6')
    def btnClicked_6(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('7')
    def btnClicked_7(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('8')
    def btnClicked_8(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('9')
    def btnClicked_9(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('+')
    def btnClicked_10(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('-')
    def btnClicked_11(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('=')
    def btnClicked_12(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('*')
    def btnClicked_13(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText(':')
    def btnClicked_14(self):
        self.ui.lineEdit.setText('.')



app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = win()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот макет:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'calc.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.13.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(320, 526)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 70, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 271, 31))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 70, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 70, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 150, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 150, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 150, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 230, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 230, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 230, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 300, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 300, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 300, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 370, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_13.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 370, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_14.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 370, 75, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial Black")
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton_15.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 320, 27))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ":"))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "."))
```

[image: макет калькулятора]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Замена происходит потому что вызывается [setText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#text-prop). Строка, что в него передается заменит, все, что было ранее в редакторе:

```
def btnClicked(self):
    self.ui.lineEdit.setText('1')
def btnClicked_1(self):
    self.ui.lineEdit.setText('2')
...
```

Чтобы, этого избежать, добавляйте старую строку, пример:

```
self.ui.lineEdit.setText(self.ui.lineEdit.text() + '1')
```